CUrl Roblox Asset using API Not Uploading
Using this (I didn't show the API due to security reasons but there is one)
I get an output (400 - Bad Request) with the error:

"The FileContent Field is required"

I'm really new to this so any help will be helpful.
curl --location --request POST 'https://apis.roblox.com/assets/v1/assets' \
--header 'x-api-key: {api-key}' \
--header 'userId: '\
--form 'request="{ 
  \"assetType\": \"Model\",  
  \"displayName\": \"Name\", 
  \"description\": \"This is a description\", 
  \"creationContext\": { 
    \"creator\": { 
      \"userId\": \"888052552\" 
    } 
  } 
}"' \
--form 'fileContent=@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rey-debida/cum/refs/heads/main/model.fbx";type=model/fbx'

Don't mind the repo name; I'm just testing.
I need help please! :c

I think you can try storing the asset into a .fbx file in your computer and then reference it instead of linking with a GitHub url?

the thing is I'm trying to hook the code up to a website for example:
I'm trying to make a website/mobile app that allows you to directly upload assets without any like things going wrong
